# which Deep learning method is best for non linear data(for classification)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

i have a dataset with variables 60 and observations 150,000, dataset is completly  non linear, and i know there are few machine learning algortihms which are good for non linear data such as SVM, but i would like to know which deep learning method is best for non linear data, any suggestion or tips would be helpful. thanks

Comment: Are you looking for accuracy, or speed?

Comment: both would be great :) but mainly the accuracy

Comment: What is your case? What are you teaching the PC to learn? I'm curious.

Comment: im trying to do classifier of 5 class

Comment: *sigh ;-). I guess you want to ask about machine learning instead of deep learning. I would say any neural network (this then would include deep learning to a certain extend) is well suited for non-linear data. Also random forests are typically quite good

Comment: so any neural net works fine ? or is there something specific net for non linear data ? like CNN is better for image classification, RNN for media

Answer (score 1):

If you speak about non-linear NN approach so the answer is: it is neural network with non-linear activation functions.

You can put only 'linear' activations and your NN (or DNN) will be like complex linear regression. But with the other activations it will restore non-linear dependence.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use any type of network but it depends on your data type.
For example,if you want to classify images,then you can use CNN for this.
If you have dynamic size of audio data,then lstm can be good because your data is not fixed-size length and it holds information temporarily.